# Abrir una nueva Activity al hacer click en un Cardview

Tags: android, android-intent, recyclerview

tengo un `Recyclerview`y un `Cardview`el problema es que deseo abrir una nueva actividad al seleccionar entre los 6 items diferentes que muestra la lista, he obtenido la posicion de los item al pulsar pero cuando intento implementar un `intent` no me funciona. desde ya gracias
Error al colocar `Intent intent = new Intent(RecyclerAdapter.this, ActividadPrincipal.class);
                    startActivity(intent);`
 me muestra el error de que el metodo no puede resolverlo y muestra `startActivity(intent);` en rojo

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] titles = {"Asistente",
            "Expositor",
            "Administrador",
            "Galeria",
            "Ubicacion",
            "Guia rapida"};

    private String[] details = {"",
            "Item two details", "Item three details",
            "Item four details", "Item file details",
            "Item six details", "Item seven details",
            "Item eight details"};

    private int[] images = { R.drawable.defecto,
            R.drawable.defecto,
            R.drawable.defecto,
            R.drawable.defecto,
            R.drawable.defecto,
            R.drawable.defecto,
            R.drawable.defecto,
            R.drawable.defecto };

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public int currentItem;
        public ImageView itemImage;
        public TextView itemTitle;
        public TextView itemDetail;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            itemTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            itemDetail = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    Snackbar.make(v, "Click detected on item " + position,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);
        viewHolder.itemDetail.setText(details[i]);
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: en el onClick no llamas a ninguna Activity

Comment: Claro que no, borre el intent ya que me daba error y solo deje el mensaje

Comment: entonces añade el error que te aparece para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ahora edite la pregunta y esta el error puntual

Comment: Algo curioso es que veo responden y casi nadie da un punto a la pregunta, \(ಠ_ಠ)/ , dar puntos no quita puntos de reputación...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declara en tu constructor lo siguiente

```
 public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 private Context context;

 public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
      this.context = context;     
 }
```

Dentro de tu onClick

```
   itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent= new Intent(context, MiNuevoActivity.class);
           context.startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
```

En el activity donde estes creando la instancia de tu RecyclerAdapter le pasas el contexto, ejemplo:

```
 //this es el contexto de tu Actividad
 new RecyclerAdapter(this);
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias ha funcionado !

Comment: más optimizado seria insertar el setOnClickListener en el CreateViewHolder

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizarlo dentro de `onBindViewHolder()` agregas un `View.OnClickListener`, asegura tener el contexto para iniciar la Actitivity (`startActivity()`), modifica el constructor para recibirlo:

```
private Context context;

     public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
          this.context = context;     
     }
```

esto sería como se realizaría de acuerdo a tu código:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtraActivity.class); 
             context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);
    viewHolder.itemDetail.setText(details[i]);
    viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);

}
```

Comment: No es mejor ponerlo en el createViewHolder? dejo referencia de donde lo he leido http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845846/why-is-adding-an-onclicklistener-inside-onbindviewholder-of-a-recyclerview-adapt

Answer (score 0):

el adaptador lleve llamar a un método que este en el fragment (o activity), que realice esta acción.

Pero primero debes declararla. Ejemplo

1) agrega al adaptador esto:

```
private NombreFragment nombreFragment;
```

2) y llamar al método del fragment (en donde detectas el clic) así:

```
nombreFragment.lanzaActividad(/*algunParametroSiDeseas*/);
```

3) Y en el fragment declarar:

```
public void lanzaActividad(/*String algunParametroSiDeseas*/){
    Intent intento = new Intent(context, CheckNuevo.class);
    /*i.putExtra("parametro", "algunParametroSiDeseas");*/
    startActivity(intento );
}
```